# How to remove the default padding of bootstrap grid column

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a grid system, and i add a table into the grid column.But the table did not cover the entire width of the column.It shows space on both left and right side.Is it happens because of the default padding of grid column?

Answer (score 3):

please provide your code first of all.

you can the `no-gutters` option : 
`Columns have horizontal padding to create the gutters between individual columns, however, you can remove the margin from rows and padding from columns with .no-gutters on the .row.`

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

```
<div class="row no-gutters">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    // stuff here for this column
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-10">
    // stuff here for columns
  </div>
</div>
```

---

OR : 
you have to see which attribute (maybe col) is adding the space (margin or padding)

i adding this in a previous project to reduce the space of all cols

```
.col, .col-1, .col-10, .col-11, .col-12, .col-2, .col-3, .col-4, .col-5, .col-6, .col-7, .col-8, .col-9, .col-auto, .col-lg, .col-lg-1, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-lg-auto, .col-md, .col-md-1, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-md-auto, .col-sm, .col-sm-1, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, .col-sm-auto, .col-xl, .col-xl-1, .col-xl-10, .col-xl-11, .col-xl-12, .col-xl-2, .col-xl-3, .col-xl-4, .col-xl-5, .col-xl-6, .col-xl-7, .col-xl-8, .col-xl-9, .col-xl-auto
 { padding: 3px !important; }
```

adjust it to your need

Comment: .no-gutters option is for padding between columns in grid. My problem is the left and right  padding  inside each grid columns

Comment: and  `.col, .col-1, . ....    xl-5, .col-xl-6, .col-xl-7, .col-xl-8, .col-xl-9, .col-xl-auto
 { padding: 0px !important; }  ?`

Answer (score 0):

If you `scss` from **Bootstrap V4** you can change gutter `width` using `variable`.

```
$grid-gutter-width: 2rem !default;
```

If you want to change `column` padding certain section. You should add custom class  and do like this.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row custom-row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.custom-row{
    margin-left: -10px;
    margin-right: -10px;
}
.custom-row .col-12{
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
/* Wild card with class */
.custom-row [class~=col]{
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
.custom-row [class*='col-']{
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
/* Wild card with global */
[class*='col-']{
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove default gutters between columns by just adding .g-0 to your columns.

```html
<div class="col g-0">
  <h1>Heading</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/gutters/#no-gutters